# How can I determine zoom level in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, zooming

I'm trying to programatically determine the zoom level in IE 11. Researching this, I've seen that Chrome and Firefox report the "actual" window.outerWidth independent of the "zoomed" window.innerWidth values - allowing for a calculation to determine zoom level. But IE 11 reports both values as having changed (outerWidth also changes when zoomed). Is there some object in IE that can be queried for "actual" window width? Or perhaps some trick to create an object that doesn't zoom when the page does? I just need something reporting dimensions independent of the zoomed content.

Comment: So I decided to just use a transparent png with a fixed px width in comparison to window width, should serve my purpose.

Comment: From your last comment, I can see that you had posted the solution for above mentioned question. If that solution solves your issue than I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. Yeah I have to wait 48 hrs and I did't want others "spinning their wheels". You're a pro as always :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to just use a transparent png with a fixed px width in comparison to window width, should serve my purpose.